# Ionic app continuously shows white screen on opening

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have developed one ionic app which works fine before June 15,2019. After that it continuously shows white screen after splash.Lazy loading is implemented in app.

I tried below steps for building apk

```
ionic cordova platform rm android
ionic cordova platform add android@8.0.0 
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-androidx 
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter
cordova plugin add cordova-android-support-gradle-release --save
```

Terminal log of app on android studio is as below

> 07-26 12:12:45.241 19749-19799/io.ionic.starter E/libEGL:
>   validate_display:255 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY) 07-26 12:12:45.521
>   19749-19782/io.ionic.starter E/AndroidProtocolHandler: Unable to open
>   asset URL:
>   file:///android_asset/www/lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.min.js 07-26
>   12:12:45.536 19749-19804/io.ionic.starter E/AndroidProtocolHandler:
>   Unable to open asset URL:
>   file:///android_asset/www/lib/ion-autocomplete/dist/ion-autocomplete.js
>   07-26 12:12:45.536 19749-19804/io.ionic.starter
>   E/AndroidProtocolHandler: Unable to open asset URL:
>   file:///android_asset/www/lib/ion-autocomplete/dist/ion-autocomplete.css
>   07-26 12:12:45.541 19749-19782/io.ionic.starter
>   E/AndroidProtocolHandler: Unable to open asset URL:
>   file:///android_asset/www/js/Calendar.js 07-26 12:12:50.181
>   19749-19749/io.ionic.starter E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent()
>   mView == null

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

1. remove android platform using
2. `ionic cordova platform rm android` remove manually `node-modules`
   and `package-lock.json` (imp*)
3. `npm cache clean --force`
4. finally run `npm i`
5. `ionic cordova build android`

Answer (score 0):

Try to debug app in browser and check developer console for error -

```
ionic cordova run browser
```

if there is no **browser** platform then you need to add platform like this-

```
ionic platform add browser
```

Answer (score 0):

Its happen only when you have an error or any librabry missing in your componant file.you can see console.log for error.if something missing added its showing the content.

Before any project start you must run this command in root of project

```
    npm install
```

then use

```
    ionic serve
```

and other answer if using this prefrence in your config.xml so please remove this line which i mantion here

```
 <preference name="CordovaWebViewEngine" value="CDVUIWebViewEngine" />
```

Comment: @lallit baghel Is it working fine on browser after ionic serve commend, but not working on apk

Comment: how much time its showing means you start application then after splash its showing or before

Comment: beghel It is showing after splash for continuously, after 5 min also white  screen is showing

Comment: remove this line if have in your config.xm file                                                             <preference name="CordovaWebViewEngine" value="CDVUIWebViewEngine" />